# Remove "Last seen on Stack Overflow" date from CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy

I think some people want to keep their SO profile private, and therefore don't link it in their CV.

But the CV displays the "Last seen on Stack Overflow" date. Then, with SEDE, it's so easy to find out the profile. This is so bad.

That date seems superfluous information for employers, so let's remove it.

Credit: this problem was noticed by [Gothdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853934/gothdo).

Comment: Get rid of this - there is no reason to state when the person was last seen on SO via their CV.  We have questions about it and it's just rude to be trying to hunt people down.  +1

Comment: We're taking a look at this and will have a more substantive answer soon. Rollout of Dev Story makes this a little more complicated than "let's just make it opt-out". Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: [last seen: yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36902/38765).

Comment: Finally implemented in 2021. smh

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've just pushed a fix to prod that hides the 'Last seen...' if you chose to hide your Stack Overflow account on your CV.

This gets a little more complex in the developer story world: the fix has been ported to the code but we use the SE network account identifier to identify the story in our candidate search product and so it appears in URLs. Next steps are to obfuscate that identifier so that it can't be used to identify your SE account from your story.

I've marked this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because the root issue has been addressed and we're working on the fixes necessary to prevent the leak when dev story is shipped.

Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: That was fast, Not at all 6-8 weeks late.

Comment: how can I deactivate it for my page if I want? I can't see any setting to do this ...

Comment: It seems this feature is back, and I want to turn it off for my profile.

Answer (score 103):

Yes please. This feature currently allows people to easily find the SO account of people who didn't list it on their CV **on purpose**.

SO Careers / Jobs in its mission is all about developer choice, and it's already offering the choice not to disclose your SE profile easily.

Please extend that choice to also cover this loophole.

Answer (score 41):

Much like a dating site profile, a CV for an account that hasn't seen a log in in a year is more likely to be a waste of time to contact. Quite simply, actively used SO accounts benefit because the dead CVs can be filtered out.

Having "last seen on SO" is useful, but fine grained information is not required for it to be useful.

Granularity something like "Currently active", "Last seen this month", "Last seen this year", "Last seen more than a year ago" should be enough.  It can be fuzzy (so someone active 28 days ago might display "last seen this year") so transitions don't pin down the last date of activity, or that could be considered too small of an attack surface to care.

The actual date makes it easy to determine who the SO account is, together with the other information.

Comment: How, and to whom is it useful?

Comment: I think this is a great middle ground - the purpose is clearly to show that the person is an active member of the SO community. An employer doesn't need to know the difference between active 8 hours ago or 9 hours ago, but knowing the *order of magnitude* of activity seems useful. Let's be honest, if you're not on Stack Overflow for something, are you really developing something? =) Honestly can't remember the last time I did a solid day of development where I didn't have to Google some random trivia about whatever library I'm working with only to get led to some SO post.

Comment: @corsiKa: Re: "Let's be honest, if you're not on Stack Overflow for something, are you really developing something?": True, but I assume that "Last seen on Stack Overflow" feature is not literally about when you last visited Stack Overflow, but rather, about when you last visited Stack Overflow *while logged in*. (Of course, that's neither here nor there as far this answer is concerned.)

Comment: @corsiKa `Let's be honest, if you're not on Stack Overflow for something, are you really developing something?` It's entirely possible that somewhere out there are libraries with sufficiently good documentation that the user can develop an entire project in them without ever having to ask for help on the internet. Or maybe the documentation is bad but they manage to get through it. Couldn't an older "last seen" time then equally indicate a developer to be _more_ competent than a newer one? Or maybe, as ruakh said, they just haven't been logging in. I don't see how this metric is useful at all.

Comment: @underscore_d "sufficiently good documentation" citation needed!  Regardless, I'm talking about activity on SO, and a SO CV.  If you aren't even visiting SO, the odds your CV is up-to-date and everything is still wired up decreases.  A lack of engagement *with SO* is a valid metric for a *SO* CV being current and active.  It isn't a perfect metric, but the perfect is the enemy of the good.

Comment: @underscore_d In theory, yes. In practice, no.

Comment: What about a "CV last updated ..." line instead? That way you get a timestamp without the crossover to SO profile if the user doesn't want it.

Comment: Yakk: In that case, I think @whrrgarbl has a better suggestion to judge recency of CVs: _include exactly that data on them_ - but as you say, not precisely enough to pinpoint them. I really wonder whether "last seen" is any indication. The best devs might be too busy developing to idly browse, & vice-versa. Perhaps if 'last CV edit' is already in the backend, we can run a query & see how much of a correlation there is between that & "last seen". That'll put all of this idle speculation to rest. "the perfect is the enemy of the good" _unless_ it's trivial to do, in which case it's just perfect

Comment: Maybe they haven't been seen on SO lately because they are passionately spending all their time working hard at their job. We wouldn't want to hire someone like that, now would we? The SO account and the job stuff should be kept separate, they are not necessarily related in any relevant ways.