# Last seen 0 days ago!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story, user-experience

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image]

It would feel more humanly if we just say something like *last seen recently*. <del>And don't even get me started on pluralization bug.</del>

Comment: Could you clarify what you think it should say instead?

Comment: I agree with the change you're asking, but what pluralization bug are you talking about?

Comment: 0 days! common!

Comment: This is not a pluralization bug, it's a zero-day exploit.

Comment: @AliDehghani http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/why-is-zero-plural

Comment: @Stijn Thanks. I didn't know that. Feel like complete idiot!

Comment: It should say "last seen today" rather than your suggested "last seen recently" IMO. Or just use hours and potentially minutes as in the main user profile.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeap it's better to say that.

Comment: Could also be "seen earlier today" or "seen xx hours ago" if you want to be specific.

Comment: At least it doesn't say `-1 days ago`. Good to know they haven't quite cracked the time travel problem... yet.

Comment: .... am I the only one who likes 0 days ago?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The time portion was removed to address [concerns with privacy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332577/remove-last-seen-on-stack-overflow-date-from-cv) (by only displaying the # of days), but I agree, `0 days ago` is weird.

1/17/2017: This is now changed to `Last seen: today`.